# How to create chart of decomposition data to categories?

Tags: plot, charts, wolfram-mathematica

I looking for programs or libraries that allow to create graphics presented below:

Idea is the following:

- W have some initial value
- It is divided to different states
- These divisions can occur some times
- We want to present name and value connected with each state

Is is possible to generate such image in `Wolfram Mathematica`? If yes which functions should I use.

[image]

Graph presented on this image shows history of usage Tinder application.

Source:

> https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/83ttdq/oc_my_28_days_on_tinder/

Comment: I have seen a chart like this on [Mathematica StackExchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) - I believe the best answer used [LogisticSigmoid](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogisticSigmoid.html) plots to draw the lines of the chart.

Comment: How to make a Sankey Diagram: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166439/how-to-make-a-sankey-diagram

Comment: This is quite near to final result. Thank you. If I create this chart I share solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to no use `Mathematica` but create this graph in `JavaScript`.

> https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/sankey-diagram/

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.SankeyDiagram);

chart.data = [
  { "from": "A", "to": "D", "value": 10 },
  { "from": "B", "to": "D", "value": 8 },
  { "from": "B", "to": "E", "value": 4 },
  { "from": "C", "to": "E", "value": 3 },
  { "from": "D", "to": "G", "value": 5 },
  { "from": "D", "to": "I", "value": 2 },
  { "from": "D", "to": "H", "value": 3 },
  { "from": "E", "to": "H", "value": 6 },
  { "from": "G", "to": "J", "value": 5 },
  { "from": "I", "to": "J", "value": 1 },
  { "from": "H", "to": "J", "value": 9 }
];

chart.dataFields.fromName = "from";
chart.dataFields.toName = "to";
chart.dataFields.value = "value";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```